# SQL Server query with multiple select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query which select all car makes and count each make quantity in response

```
SELECT 
    q.Make, Count(q.ID)
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         cars.ID, cars.Make, cars.Model, 
         cars.Year1, cars.Month1, cars.KM, cars.VIN,
         cars.Fuel, cars.EngineCap, cars.PowerKW, 
         cars.GearBox, cars.BodyType, cars.BodyColor, 
         cars.Doors, cars.FullName, Transport.address,
         (DateDiff(second,Getdate(),cars.AuEnd)) as r, 
         cars.AuEnd, cars.BuyNowPrice, cars.CurrentPrice
     FROM 
         cars 
     LEFT JOIN 
         Transport ON Cars.TransportFrom = Transport.ID 
     WHERE 
         Active = 'True' 
         AND AuEnd > GETDATE() 
         AND year1 >= 1900 AND year1 <= 2015 
         AND Make in ('AUDi', 'AIXAM', 'ALPINA')
    ORDER BY 
         cars.make ASC, cars.model ASC 
         OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY) AS q 
GROUP BY 
    q.make ORDER BY q.make ASC;
```

Now I need get in result as third field each make total count without offset,
so now I get result

```
Make   CountInResponse  
AIXAM   1                
ALPINA  1                
AUDI    48
```

But I need to get

```
Make   CountInResponse   Total
AIXAM   1                 1
ALPINA  1                 1
AUDI    48                100
```

I think I need something like

```
SELECT 
    q.Make, Count(q.ID),
    (SELECT Make, Count(ID) 
     FROM cars 
     WHERE Active = 'True' AND AuEnd > GETDATE() 
       AND year1 >= 1900 AND year1 <= 2015 
       AND Make in ('AUDI', 'AIXAM', 'ALPINA')
     GROUP BY Make) as q2
FROM 
    (SELECT              
         cars.ID, cars.Make, cars.Model, 
         cars.Year1, cars.Month1, cars.KM, cars.VIN,
         cars.Fuel, cars.EngineCap, cars.PowerKW, 
         cars.GearBox, cars.BodyType, cars.BodyColor, 
         cars.Doors, cars.FullName, Transport.address,
         (DateDiff(second,Getdate(),cars.AuEnd)) as r, 
         cars.AuEnd, cars.BuyNowPrice, cars.CurrentPrice
     FROM 
         cars 
     LEFT JOIN 
         Transport ON Cars.TransportFrom = Transport.ID 
     WHERE 
         Active = 'True' 
         AND AuEnd > GETDATE() 
         AND year1 >= 1900 AND year1 <= 2015 
         AND Make in ('AUDi', 'AIXAM', 'ALPINA')
    ORDER BY 
         cars.make ASC, cars.model ASC 
         OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY) AS q
```

But I get an error

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

How to write right syntax?

Comment: First you need to tell what value you have to show in `q2`. You are selecting two columns in `q2` (ie)`Make, Count(ID)` you cannot do that in `sql server`

Comment: Fisrt Count is for offseted query second for total Count without offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are selecting two columns in `q2` (ie) `Make, Count(ID)` you cannot do that in SQL Server.

Try something like this.

```
WITH cte AS 
( 
    SELECT    
        row_number() OVER(order by cars.make ASC,cars.model ASC) AS rn, 
        cars.id, cars.make 
    FROM      
        cars 
    LEFT JOIN 
        transport ON cars.transportfrom = transport.id 
    WHERE     
        active = 'True' 
        AND auend > getdate() 
        AND year1 >= 1900 AND year1 <= 2015 
        AND make IN ('AUDI', 'AIXAM', 'ALPINA')
) 
SELECT   
    make , 
    count(CASE WHEN RN BETWEEN 50 AND 100 THEN 1 END) AS countinresponse, 
    count(1) AS total 
FROM 
    cte 
GROUP BY 
    make
```

Or you need to convert the `sub-query` in `select` to `correlated sub-query`

```
SELECT   q.make, 
         Count(q.id) countinresponse, 
         ( 
                  SELECT   Count(id) 
                  FROM     cars C1 
                  WHERE    c1.id = q.id 
                  AND      active='True' 
                  AND      auend > Getdate() 
                  AND      year1 >= 1900 
                  AND      year1 <= 2015 
                  AND      make IN ('AUDi', 
                                    'AIXAM', 
                                    'ALPINA') 
                  GROUP BY make) AS total 
FROM     ( 
                   SELECT    cars.id, 
                             cars.make 
                   FROM      cars 
                   LEFT JOIN transport 
                   ON        cars.transportfrom=transport.id 
                   WHERE     active='True' 
                   AND       auend > Getdate() 
                   AND       year1 >= 1900 
                   AND       year1 <= 2015 
                   AND       make IN ('AUDi', 
                                      'AIXAM', 
                                      'ALPINA') 
                   ORDER BY  cars.make ASC, 
                             cars.model ASC offset 50 rowsfetch next 50 rows only ) AS q 
GROUP BY q.make 
ORDER BY q.make ASC;
```

Comment: Are you sure he uses 2012 ?

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Column 'q.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Yeah because he is using it in his query and the error is not about`offset` so i guess its `2012`

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - thats weird `q.id` is present inside count aggregate. Try the other query

Comment: Another got error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'cars'.`

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - missed order by in `row_number`. try now

Comment: Oh sorry everething like a sharm. Thanks